# Openstreetmap: embedding map in webpage (like Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, maps, openstreetmap

Is there a way to embed/mashup the OpenStreetMap in your page (like the way [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) works)?

I need to show a map inside my page with some markers and allow dragging/zooming around, maybe routing.
I suspect there would be some Javascript API for this, but I can't seem to find it.

Searching gets me an [API for access to raw map data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API), but that seems to be more for map editing; besides, working with that would be a heavy task for AJAX.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to use some JavaScript stuff to show your map. OpenLayers is the number one choice for this.

There is an example at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example and something more advanced at

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Marker

and

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_POI_layer_example

Answer (score 55):

### Simple OSM Slippy Map Demo/Example

Click on "Run code snippet" to see an embedded OpenStreetMap slippy map with a marker on it. This was created with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com).

#### Code

```js
// Where you want to render the map.
var element = document.getElementById('osm-map');

// Height has to be set. You can do this in CSS too.
element.style = 'height:300px;';

// Create Leaflet map on map element.
var map = L.map(element);

// Add OSM tile layer to the Leaflet map.
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// Target's GPS coordinates.
var target = L.latLng('47.50737', '19.04611');

// Set map's center to target with zoom 14.
map.setView(target, 14);

// Place a marker on the same location.
L.marker(target).addTo(map);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="osm-map"></div>
```

#### Specs

- Uses OpenStreetMaps.
- Centers the map to the target GPS.
- Places a marker on the target GPS.
- Only uses Leaflet as a dependency.

**Note:**

I used the CDN version of [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com) here, but you can [download](http://leafletjs.com/download.html) the files so you can serve and include them from your own host.

Comment: I used your code in a javascript function, and it works like a charm.
But again, triggering that function, enlarges osm map and destroys everything. Any solution ?

Comment: @0x48piraj Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem, or even better: ask a new question with your code that shows whats wrong.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks a lot! One question though: at `var target = L.latLng()` you clearly define the coordinates. Any chance of showing how to implement the case where the coordinates for several dots are stored inside a JSON structure? Thanks!

Comment: That is used only for the view where the map's center should be located. You add the markers with `L.marker(target).addTo(map);` Just loop your structure and create as many `L.latLng()`s as you need and pass those to `L.marker()`.

Comment: @LucasAimaretto Here's an example defining an array of three markers and looping through it: http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/marker-array.view.html

Answer (score 42):

There's now also [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), which is built with mobile devices in mind.

There is a [Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) for leaflet. Besides basic features such as markers, with plugins it also supports [routing](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing) using an external service.

For a simple map, it is IMHO easier and faster to set up than OpenLayers, yet fully configurable and tweakable for more complex uses.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to embed an OSM map on a webpage, the easiest way is to get the iframe code directly from the OSM website:

1. Navigate to the map you want on https://www.openstreetmap.org
2. On the right side, click the "Share" icon, then click "HTML"
3. Copy the resulting iframe code directly into your webpage. It should look like this:

```html
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-62.04673002474011%2C16.95487694424327%2C-61.60521696321666%2C17.196751341562923&amp;layer=mapnik" 
style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
<br/><small><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/17.0759/-61.8260">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

If you want to do something more elaborate, see OSM wiki "[Deploying your own Slippy Map](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Deploying_your_own_Slippy_Map)".

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [mapstraction](http://mapstraction.com/).  This can give you more flexibility to provide maps based on google, osm, yahoo, etc however your code won't have to change.

Comment: their website seems to be down.

Comment: It works, but only without the "www" Subdomain: http://mapstraction.com/ ..exactly what I searched, thanks for that!

Comment: mapstraction isn't maintained for almost 10 years now :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use OpenLayers (js API for maps).

There's an [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials-spherical-mercator.html) on their page showing how to embed OSM tiles.

Edit: New [Link to OpenLayers examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks a lot. I can only accept one answer though, so it goes to the more detailed one.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

I would also take a look at [CloudMade's developer tools](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects).  They offer a beautifully styled OSM base map service, an OpenLayers plugin, and even their own light-weight, very fast JavaScript mapping client.  They also host their own routing service, which you mentioned as a possible requirement.  They have great documentation and examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/), as simple as this (run the code):

```js
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)

// add the OpenStreetMap tiles
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  { subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'] })
  .addTo(mymap)
```

```css
#mapid { height: 280px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
   
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still stumbling here, there are now tools that don't require you to be a developer and are as easy to use but much more versatile than Google My Maps, such as [FacilMap](https://facilmap.org) and [uMap](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/new).

Just add some markers and then fetch your embeddable iframe, which can be set to be interactive as well :)

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to do it if you fear Javascript...I'm still learning. Open Street makes a simple Wordpress plugin you can customize. Add OSM Widget plugin.

This will be a filler until I figure out my Python Java concotion using coverter TIGER line files from the Census Bureau.

Comment: Me, I'm far more worried about Wordpress than JS, but that's a matter of opinion. Thank you :)

Comment: Btw TIGER is US-only.